# performance issues

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, caching, scalability

We are running an ASP.NET application and now our traffic has increased a lot which resulted in slow response time to users. We have optimized the application and the database but still the desired response time is not achieved. We have tried ASP.NET Cache but it didn’t help either. What are the other options that I can try? I am looking for a scalable solution that should be able to handle more traffic in future.

Comment: did you considered your webserver hardware resources relative to number of requests?that might also be important if you are getting expected output from the optimum capabilities of your web server hardware resources. eg: putting a extra RAM might be a good option how ever do a research beforehand using performance counters etc

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is on your database - then you need to optimize better, better hardware, dba analysis, etc.

If the problem is a slow web app you need to profile and figure out *exactly* where the slowness is happening. This is much to vague of a question here. Download ANTS Profile or write your own trace output (ants is easier IMHO) and see where your app is slowing down. Is it because of session locks, database, linq queries executing time and time (for instance calling query.Count() will re-execute the query every single time) etc etc

Check your viewstate size - use the tool fiddler to investigate page size, time to first byte, etc.

This is a vague question but these are some basic items.

We need more info but this should get you started.

Comment: your answer of 'upgrading' doesnt tell us where or what. Are your drives optimized on cluster size for reads. Are your file groups optimized for read/write, etc.etc.  However-you mention you are storing sessions in sql server.That is going to be a hit there right now as potentialyl every request has database overhead with it.  State server should help a bit as per: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/p2pstateserver.aspx  so then likely your issue is elsewhere if it didnt. Why not disable viewstate for some controls and rebind data from the cache for example as a test (or disable all together)

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net cache itself has some limitation and performance issues. It doesn't make app scalable because it is in-proc in nature. However if scalability is your major concern then you need to implement Distributed Caching. Distributed Cache can make application highly scalable. Basically In-memory distributed caching is a form of caching that allows the cache to span multiple servers so that it can grow in size and in transactional capacity. It is also a very scalable because of its architecture. It distributes it works across multiple servers but still gives you a logical view of a single cache.  I’d rather suggest you NCache on the behalf of my experience. For further details just go through this article  [“improve asp.net app performance and scalability”](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/asp-net-performance-scalability.html).  It’ll surly help you.

Comment: Thanks Nelly, we are already evaluating NCache and some other third party cache providers.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to emphasize on the answer of @AdamTuliper in regards to the ViewState

You might be having a lot of GridViews that get populated with huge data.
Consider turning ViewState off if not required. Meaning: if the user does not interact with the gridview (by selecting a row, updating, etc..) then there is no need for the grid view to go back and forth between server and client.

If however, this is not the case, then we will need more info to be able to provide help.

Comment: We’ve upgraded the hardware to the latest technology. We are storing our sessions in MSSQL server and I think the first bottleneck is the SQL Server as it doesn’t seem to be scalable
 We have done some testing with SQL server and issues arise when the numbers of users exceed 15000. We’ve tried Session State Server but it didn't help
Part of our app is heavily using ViewState and we are trying to reduce the VS size but that is something that  we can do. We are trying to write a custom VS store where we'll keep the large VS in the local cache instead of keeping it in the ASP.NET response